# Executing statements while a result set is open (JDBC/JAVA)

Tags: java, jdbc

Is it safe or recommended to execute independent statements while you have a result open? Does it matter if they are attached to a different connection or the same one as the result set? I'm particularly concerned with **how the result holds locks if any, which could cause deadlock.**

Ex.

```
while(resultSet.next()) {
     Execute separate statements in here ( same or different connection )
}
```

Also is a result set backed by an underlying cursor or something else?

Ty

Comment: I thought u could have two open statements from the same connection, is this wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several questions here.

First, generally "yes" it is possible and common to run other SQL statements while iterating over a `ResultSet`.  And yes, `ResultSets` are backed by a cursor.

It is also possible to create a deadlock doing this, so you just need to be aware of that.  If the SQL being executed inside of your loop is not modifying rows in the same table as the `ResultSet`, then you should ensure that the `ResultSet` is created with a concurrency mode of `CONCUR_READ_ONLY`, and in general try to use `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

For example:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                                     ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

If you use `CONCUR_READ_ONLY` and `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` in general locks that block writes should not be generated.  Using the same `Connection` object is also recommended because then both the cursor and the SQL that is modifying other objects are within the same transaction and are therefore less likely to cause a deadlock.

Comment: The occurrence of such a deadlock depends on the database. Also autocommit needs to be disabled to use multiple statement concurrently on the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

Its safe according to my point of view..

> The ResultSet is usually linked to the Statement which is usually linked to the Connection.
>   A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object
>   that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next
>   result from a sequence of multiple results.
>
> **Close ResultSet when finished**
>
> Close `ResultSet` object as soon as you finish
>   working with `ResultSet` object even
>   though `Statement` object closes the
>   `ResultSet` object implicitly when it
>   closes, closing `ResultSet` explicitly
>   gives chance to garbage collector to
>   recollect memory as early as possible
>   because `ResultSet` object may occupy
>   lot of memory depending on query.
>
> `ResultSet.close();`

Comment: I'd suggest that rather than use `ResultSet.close()`, anyone developing for Java 7 (i.e. just about all programmers not targeting Android these days, I'd imagine) should be using *try-with-resources*.  Getting the code to correctly clean up an SQL statement throwing an exception right is actually quite tricky if you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly safe.  You have two basic choices:

- Use a different Connection object.
- Use the same Connection object.

The primary difference is in how transactions are handled.

- Different Connections are always in different transactions
- Different statements in the same Connection can be made to be in the same transaction if you set auto commit mode to false.

Two statements that are not in the same transaction are guaranteed by the SQL server not to interfere with each other (usually this means that the server will hold onto copies of any modified data if an older transaction might still need it).  It is also down to the server how it performs locking (if at all) but it must guarantee that no deadlock can occur.  Usually it does this by a process called serialization, which involves storing transactions in a log until they can be guaranteed to execute without deadlock.